# Is it possible to call page in MVC project from an exist WebForm Project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a huge web form project (let's say project A), I want to write some new feature in MVC (project B)
How can I from aspx page in project A call to MVC controller in project B

Comment: What do you mean by "call to"? Do you mean make an HTTP request? Or call a method directly on the server?

Comment: a HTTP request is a HTTP request, any application can make a HTTP request to any other. Whether the second application is designed to receive and answer them in a desirable way is another matter - MVC controllers generally return HTML Views, which wouldn't be much use to another application most of the time, unless it's just a partial view of HTML which can be inserted into an existing page, e.g. via AJAX. Unless maybe your particular action method returns JSON or XML in this case, then the first app can make use of that data ? It's not clear what the scenario is, your question is too vague

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you have to follow below given steps-

1. If you are logging into A directly , then login into B internally from A using post request. Similarly if you are logging into B directly then login into A internally from using post request. This will handle the authorization and authentication for both A & B.
2. Use HTTP requests to redirect between both applications A & B. To call pages from B use http link to action methods in B and to call page from A use link to aspx page.
3. On logout button click in either application, do logout from both applications.